# Create only one account in accountmanager

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager

I am using my own AccountAuthenticator for my app to create account. But can I restrict or give warning to the user that he/she cant create another account for my app(like whatsapp). If can I want to know about those actions. So please provide me some information or tutorials about it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: See that post: [here][1]. Through answers you'll make your way.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832046/disallow-multiple-accounts-in-accountmanager

Comment: thanks for your response @SylOR. I will go through it.